Gradle build fails in React Native: Could not find react-native-gradle-plugin and kotlin-gradle-plugin artifacts
I'm working on a React Native project, and I've been encountering issues while building my Android app. I've followed various upgrade steps and adjustments, but I can't seem to resolve the following error:
Error
When running the command:
npx react-native run-android

I get the following build error:


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'AppBarFrontend'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:.

     Required by:

         root project :

   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:.

     Required by:

         root project :



1. Checked my build.gradle file: I have defined the appropriate versions for Gradle, React Native, and Kotlin. Here is my build.gradle file:


buildscript {

    ext {

        buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"

        minSdkVersion = 24

        compileSdkVersion = 35

        targetSdkVersion = 34

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"

        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"

    }

    repositories {

        google()

        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2")

        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:0.75.3")

        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")

    }

}



allprojects {

    repositories {

        google()

        mavenCentral()

    }

}



2. Cleaned and reinstalled dependencies:
I ran
./gradlew clean and npm install

but I still get the same error.
3. React Native Version:
I'm using React Native 0.75.3 and have
react-native-community/cli

set to version 14.1.0.
Additional Configuration:
I'm working in a Windows environment using VS Code.
My gradle-wrapper.properties file has the following configuration:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10-all.zip

Why are com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin and kotlin-gradle-plugin not being found, despite being correctly specified in the build.gradle file? Is it possible that I'm missing a repository configuration or there is a version conflict somewhere?
I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

What version of RN did you upgrade from? Assuming you did so since you mentioned it.

I upgraded from React Native 0.71.x to 0.75.3, and made adjustments according to React Native Upgrade Helper to align with the latest versions of Gradle and Kotlin.  And I initially tried leaving the Gradle version unspecified in build.gradle, but it resulted in errors stating that the Gradle plugin version couldn't be found. I ended up specifying classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2"), but the build still fails with the same issues related to missing artifacts like react-native-gradle-plugin and kotlin-gradle-plugin

Since that is quite a leap, between 0.71 to 0.75.3, maybe trying upgrading to a version in-between and seeing if that works. Then, you might have less changes to make.

That makes sense! I’ll try upgrading incrementally from 0.71.x to 0.72.x or 0.73.x first, and see if that resolves the build issues before jumping to 0.75.3. Hopefully, it will require fewer changes along the way. I’ll update you with the results after attempting this approach

Thanks for your help! The build is now successful, but I'm facing a new issue. When I run the app on the Android emulator, it briefly opens and then closes immediately. I've cleared the cache, rebuilt the project, and no errors are shown in the terminal. I'm using React Native 0.72 with Android SDK 33. The Metro terminal shows this warning:
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running.
Despite the build being successful, the app doesn't stay open. Any advice on this?

I would suggest opening a new question and adding all the relevant information there.

Right, I did it. Still the issue but not giving up. Thanks for your recommendation
